# Adding a custom column to a pyspark dataframe using udf passing columns as an argument

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe having two columns and I am trying to add a new column referring a new value for these columns. I am taking this values from a dictionary which contains the correct value for the column

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|       country|                 zip|
+--------------+--------------------+
|        Brazil|                7541|
|United Kingdom|                5678|
|         Japan|                1234|
|       Denmark|                2345|
|        Canada|                4567|
|         Italy|                6031|
|        Sweden|                4205|
|        France|                6111|
|         Spain|                8555|
|         India|                2552|
+--------------+--------------------+
```

The correct value for the country should be India and zip should be 1234 and that is stored in a dictionary

```
column_dict = {'country' : 'India', zip: 1234}
```

I am trying to make the new column value as "Brazil: India, Zip :1234" where the value of the column is anything different from these values.

I have tried it in following way but it's returning empty column but the function is returning the desired value

```
     cols = list(df.columns)
     col_list = list(column_dict.keys())

def update(df, cols = cols , col_list = col_list):
   z = []
   for col1, col2 in zip(cols,col_list):
      if col1 == col2:
         if df.col1 != column_dict[col2]: 
            z.append("{'col':" + col2  + ", 'reco': " + str(column_dict[col2]) + "}")   
         else:
            z.append("{'col':" + col2  + ", 'reco': }")

my_udf = udf(lambda x: update(x, cols, col_list))
z = y.withColumn("NewValue", lit(my_udf(y, cols,col_list)))
```

If I export the same output dataframe to csv value is coming with the parts appending with '\'. How can I get the function value on the column in exact way?

Comment: what kind of dataframe you are expecting? Your question is not very clear... Can you tell us the outcome you are interested for?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to make a dataframe from your `dictionary` and `union()` it to your main dataframe and then `groupby` and get the `last` value. here you can do this:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

newDf = sc.parallelize([
    {'country' : 'India', 'zip': 1234}
]).toDF()

newDF.show()
```

newDF:

```
+-------+----+
|country| zip|
+-------+----+
|  India|1234|
+-------+----+
```

and finalDF:

```
unionDF = df.union(newDF)

unionDF.show()
+--------------+--------------------+
|       country|                 zip|
+--------------+--------------------+
|        Brazil|                7541|
|United Kingdom|                5678|
|         Japan|                1234|
|       Denmark|                2345|
|        Canada|                4567|
|         Italy|                6031|
|        Sweden|                4205|
|        France|                6111|
|         Spain|                8555|
|         India|                2552|
|         India|                1234|
+--------------+--------------------+
```

and in the end do `groupby` and `last`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

finalDF = unionDF.groupbby('country').agg(f.last('zip'))

finalDF.show()

+--------------+--------------------+
|       country|                 zip|
+--------------+--------------------+
|        Brazil|                7541|
|United Kingdom|                5678|
|         Japan|                1234|
|       Denmark|                2345|
|        Canada|                4567|
|         Italy|                6031|
|        Sweden|                4205|
|        France|                6111|
|         Spain|                8555|
|         India|                1234|
+--------------+--------------------+
```